# HTML/DOM: What is standards equivalent of document.body.scrollHeight?

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, html, quirks-mode

For nearly a decade i've been using:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

to return the "*ideal*" height of the browser window. This worked fine when i was *forcing* Internet Explorer into ***quirks mode***, by using a quirks-mode doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Now i want to opt into ***standards mode***, except [the meaning of `scrollHeight` has changed](http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/using-doctype-invalidates-client-height-t100424.html):

- **Quirks Mode**: `document.body.scrollHeight` = the height of the document
- **Standards Mode**: `document.body.scrollHeight` = the height of the `<body>` element

What is the standards mode equivalent of `document.body.scrollHeight`?

### See also

- quirksmode.org: [W3C DOM Compatibility - CSS Object Model View - ElementView properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36)
- [Using !DOCTYPE invalidates client height](http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/using-doctype-invalidates-client-height-t100424.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.documentElement.scrollHeight` I believe.

For viewport it's `window.innerHeight` for modern browsers.

If the above aren't what you want, here's a list of a bunch of them:

- document.documentElement.[scrollHeight,clientHeight,offsetHeight]
- document.body.[scrollHeight,clientHeight,offsetHeight]
- window.[inner,outer][Height,Width] ( modern browsers only )

Comment: That did it, changing code `document.body.getAttribute("scrollHeight", 0)` to `document.documentElement.getAttribute("scrollHeight", 0)` when IE is hosted inside a Win32 application.