# iFrame auto-height firefox latest

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I'm trying to create a firefox auto-height function this what i got so far:

```
try {
        var iframe = parent.document.getElementById('container-iframe');
        var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
        if (innerDoc.body.offsetHeight) {
            /*iframe.height = */console.log(innerDoc.body.offsetHeight + 32); //Extra height FireFox
        } else if (iframe.Document && iframe.Document.body.scrollHeight) {
            /*iframe.height = */console.log(iframe.Document.body.scrollHeight);
        }
        else {
            console.log("None were found");
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
```

This works like a charm on Chrome and Safari. But always reply None were found on the console for Firefox. I'm testing this with firefox 26 on linux and Firefox 25 on MacOS, both behave the same way.

Is there any reason why firefox doesn't fill these values? Is there any other property i could use for this same purpose?.

I've looked around for this, and it appears these worked for some version of firefox, but they don't anymore.

Comment: `scrollHeight` of the document object itself should do it.

Comment: I can't find a scrollHeight property on the document object in the DOM.

Comment: This link has some interesting reading: http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

Comment: Sorry, meant `documentElement` of the iframe. And see also http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788830/html-dom-what-is-standards-equivalent-of-scrollheight

Comment: all of them are set to 0, I've tried all of those. I had to go with a a cross-domain jquery plugin solution. But I'm still wondering if there's a simpler way to do this. Why is it that firefox doesn't define those properties and the rest of the browsers does.